# catching warnings from numpy and scipy with try except

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statsmodels

I'm fitting an ExponentialSmoothing model from statsmodels with version 0.10.1 (statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing) - I have to do this repeatedly on groups in a pandas groupby object, but the point is I'm looping through datasets to fit a new model on each group of data.

In some iterations of the loop, but not all, statsmodels raises a ConvergenceWarning, or a RuntimeWarning, and I want to capture these warnings and record them in the result dataframe next to the prediction.

I've tried using a warnings context manager so that I can raise warnings like they're exceptions, and added try/except blocks

The problem with this approach is that if one of these warnings gets caught, the model isn't actually fit because the try block gets skipped and, worst of all, I end up predicting using a model fit on a previous iteration.

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing, HoltWintersResults
from statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions import ConvergenceWarning
import numpy as np
from loguru import logger

concat_region_keys = []
forecast_result_dfs = []
region_df_groups = deseasonalized_search_counts \
    .sort_index() \
    .groupby('region_id') \
    ['region_deseasonalized_observations']
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("error")
    for i, (region_id, df_region_group) in enumerate(region7_df_groups):
        concat_region_keys.append(region_id)
        region_guard_rail = df_region_group.iloc[-1]  # most recent observation
        err_msg = np.nan
        try:
            holt_winters_result_object = ExponentialSmoothing(endog=df_region_group).fit()
        except ConvergenceWarning as ce:
            logger.warning(f"{i} region {region_id}: ConvergenceWarning {ce}")
            err_msg = f"ConvergenceWarning: {ce}"
        except RuntimeWarning as re:
            logger.warning(f"{i} region {region_id}: RuntimeWarning {re}")
            err_msg = f"RuntimeWarning: {re}"
        forecast_result = holt_winters_result_object \
            .forecast(periods_ahead) \
            .assign(
                fit_call_warning=err_msg,
            )
        forecast_result_dfs.append(forecast_result)
```

What's the correct way, with try/except or some other python construct, to do the following for each iteration of the loop?

1. fit the model
2. capture any warnings that were raised so I can record them in a variable or dataframe.

Comment: Do the warnings invalidate the result of `ExponentialSmoothing` at all? If not, and you want to use both the result and any warnings produced, you should return both from the function instead of raising them like Exceptions. Can you include the content of `ExponentialSmoothing` as well?

Comment: It seems like this is a good case for [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops). So you'd log the errors as you want then add a `continue` at the end of the except blocks, that way it just moves onto the next iteration, instead of predicting the model when it shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

One issue is this

"In some iterations of the loop, but not all, statsmodels raises a ConvergenceWarning, or a RuntimeWarning, and I want to capture these warnings and record them in the result dataframe next to the prediction."

You can't capture a prediction that threw an error the error was the output of the function. You can save the predictions up to the point an error occurred. You need to decided what you want to do with your model after it throws an error like that. You could use continue like @ALollz said or you could move on to the next group you want to fit but that is a decision you need to make. It's a design choice wether to abandon the set that threw an error while fitting or decide to move on, we can't decide that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this website
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/369/warnings.filterwarnings

Use the `with` statement

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
```